# Using variables from other scenes (Godot)

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have two scenes (Profile and Login) and I want to use the variable new_profile from Profile and use it in Login but when I autoload Profile and mark it as a singleton it doesn't let me run the program and gives me an index error and says that the nodes referenced in my variables do not exist even though before I autoloaded it, it worked perfectly fine

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please be sure to include your code and the Minimum Reproducible  Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You would use a singleton to achieve this task.  Godot calls it, autoload.  Goto Project -> Project Settings -> Autoload.  Click on the folder icon.  Add your gdscript file with the variables needed.  That will auto populate the field directly to the right.  You can edit this name as you wish.  Then click on add.  When you play your program, those variables will be accessible by any script by way of this code.  Godot official explanation and code available [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html).

PlayerVariables (added to Autoload)

```
var player_vars = get_node("/root/PlayerVariables")

player_vars.health -= 10
```

Or

```
PlayerVariables.health -= 10
```